# Issue in GETTING Instagram followers list in android

Tags: android, json, instagram

**Relevant code:**

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser
    .getJSONFromUrlByGet("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"
    + userInfo.get(InstagramApp.TAG_ID) +
    "/follows?access_token="
    + instagramApp.getmAccessToken());
```

> Data of jsonObject is as below

```
{"pagination":{},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

Where could I possibly go wrong? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, it is a sandbox user limitation, try to add another sandbox user via Manage Clients on Instagram website and recheck.

Comment: thanx for your ans How to add another sandbox in single user